# How do I install cakephp bake on my hosting

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I've managed to install and use cake bake with xampp, but I have no idea how to install bake with my command line on the hosting.

The error I get is:

> CakePHP 3.4.4 Red Velvet already installed.

Can anyone give me some directions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just `cd` to your `/path/to/project/bin/` and execute the Cake command line tool with `./cake bake model Products`, for example. ✌

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am in the /bin/ directory, but when I type cake bake it sais: unknown command.

I'm using PSFTP in cmd.

Comment: Please note the leading `./` – so try this, when you are inside the folder: `./cake`

Comment: Not working. in the /bin/ folder there are three files; cake, cake.bat and cake.php.

Comment: Make sure that a PHP CLI is available on the system. Also check this doc: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Comment: Can't run anything. How do I check if there is a PHP CLI on my server? php -v is not working also....

Comment: Depends on your system, but maybe this helps. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10976/how-do-i-install-a-php-cli-with-a-usable-interactive-prompt-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: Thank you! I have some directions now. Hopefully I manage to work it out!